# c# Webview2 mirror in two different forms

Tags: c#, webview2

is there anyway to clone or mirror a webview2 object in c#?
I need it to show on two different forms and be able to access it in at least one of them.

Comment: Can you share some code? What have you tried, and where are you getting stuck?

Comment: Please be more specific. Webview2 loads a webpage and has a lot of stuff under the covers, so to speak, like folders for cookies and navigation events. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: What i'm trying to do is displaying a webview2 on two different forms. i need a "master form" controlling form2 that is showing on a fullscreen on screen 2